# Using repository pattern, what lamda expression to use to access sub class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-entities, repository-pattern

I am using repository pattern and I am struggling with how to join two classes using lamda expression. What is the best approach to use GenericRepository class? I am new to this design pattern. I have seen in some site that suggest not to expose LINQ in Repository class [This suggest not to expose LINQ in repository class](http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/repository-pattern-done-right/) If we don't use LINQ in repository class, what is the best option to join two tables(classes)?

I have the following tables as shown in ER diagram [ER diagram for playlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgFak.jpg)

1)PlayList

```
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // <auto-generated>
    //     This code was generated from a template.
    //
    //     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
    //     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
    // </auto-generated>
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    namespace MusicCloud.Model.EFModel
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        public partial class PlayList
        {
            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
            public PlayList()
            {
                this.PlayListSongs = new HashSet<PlayListSong>();
            }

            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> CreatedDate { get; set; }
            public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> ModifiedDate { get; set; }

            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
            public virtual ICollection<PlayListSong> PlayListSongs { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

2) PlayListSong

```
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // <auto-generated>
        //     This code was generated from a template.
        //
        //     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
        //     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
        // </auto-generated>
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        namespace MusicCloud.Model.EFModel
        {
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;

            public partial class PlayListSong
            {
                public int PUSongId { get; set; }
                public int PlistId { get; set; }
                public int SongId { get; set; }
                public string UserId { get; set; }

                public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
                public virtual PlayList PlayList { get; set; }
                public virtual Song Song { get; set; }
            }
        }
```

**In UnitofWork class, I have**

```
 /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public GenericRepository<PlayList> PlayListRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._playListRepository == null)
                this._playListRepository = new GenericRepository<PlayList>(_context);
            return _playListRepository;
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public GenericRepository<PlayListSong> PlayListSongRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._playListSongRepository == null)
                this._playListSongRepository = new GenericRepository<PlayListSong>(_context);
            return _playListSongRepository;
        }
    }
```

How do I implement something like this

```
    namespace MusicCloud.Services
            {
                public class PlayListServices : IPlayListServices
                {
                    private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;


                    public PlayListServices(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
                    {
                        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
                    }

     public IEnumerable<PlayListEntity> GetAllPlayLists(string userId)
        {      

        string[] includes = { "PlayList", "PlayListSong" };
        var playLists =_unitOfWork.PlayListSongRepository.GetWithMultipleInclude(
                                 e => e.UserId==userId,includes
                                ).Select(x=>x.PlayList).ToList();

                   if (playLists.Any())
                        {

                            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
                            {
                                cfg.CreateMap<PlayList, PlayListEntity>();                                });

                             var playListsModel = Mapper.Map<List<PlayList>, List<PlayListEntity>>(playLists);
                            return playListsModel;
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                   }
                   }
```

I want to get all the playlists(playlist names) created by a user.
How do I join Playlist and PlayListSong to filter by userId? The code below gives error.

```
string[] includes = { "PlayList", "PlayListSong" };
        var playLists =_unitOfWork.PlayListSongRepository.GetWithMultipleInclude(
                                 e => e.UserId==userId,includes
                                ).Select(x=>x.PlayList).ToList();




         /// <summary>
            /// Inclue multiple
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="predicate"></param>
            /// <param name="include"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetWithMultipleInclude(
                System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, string[] include)
            {
                IQueryable<TEntity> query = this.DbSet;
                foreach (string inc in include)
                {
                    query = query.Include(inc);
                }

                return query.Where(predicate).ToList<TEntity>() ;
            }
```

Or is there a better way to achieve this only using the PlayListRepository and PlayListSongRepository only without lamda expression? What is best appropriate approach? Similaryly if I need to update multiple related tables, how do I perform the update,using lamda or just PlayListRepository and PlayListSongRepository only?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are using the Repository Pattern and Unit of Work pattern? I would suggest studying the documentation of DbContext. It clearly states that `A DbContext instance represents a combination of the Unit Of Work and Repository patterns such that it can be used to query from a database and group together changes that will then be written back to the store as a unit. DbContext is conceptually similar to ObjectContext.`
I dont understand the need to add another layer of repository or unit of work.
[check here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Each service class should inherit from base service layer where you should have an instance of DbContext and simply query to your tables in your service layer based on your Business logic.

Comment: abdul samad-I know how to implement it with DBContext which is easy. Right now, I'm learning design pattern(repository pattern) with dependecy injection. I just want to know if repository pattern is widely used as design pattern in real client projects in IT companies, then what is the best approach for above scenario or complex queries?

Comment: so what exactly is your problem? Getting repository + unitofwork to work or querying the data?
As per querying the data is concerned I see a flaw in your model. `PlayList` should have a `public virtual ICollection<PlayListSong> PlayListSongs { get; set; }` and in your `PlayListSong` PlayList, Song and AspNetUser should be added as foreign keys using the `virtual` keyword. Then whenever u query a PlayList by Id you will get all the related info, PlayListSongs etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in PlayListSong You have

```
public virtual PlayList PlayList { get; set; }
```

The easiest way to get playLists is to enable lazy loading, and just get all playlist from play list songs.

I don't know how Your repo looks, but if You have something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T>`GetAll()
    {
        return db.Set<T>();
    }
```

Then just get it like this:

```
_unitOfWork.PlayListSongRepository.GetAll()
    .Where(x => x.UserId == userId).Select(x => x.PlayList).Distinct();
```

Just remember to enable lazy loading.